# Get private repositories with OAuth in Android

Tags: api, github, retrofit

I implemented OAuth and get `access_token` and `token_type` and don't really understand how to get list of private and public repos of authenticated user.

The documentation says to do this:

```
GET /users/:username/repos
```

but when the user is authorized, in response I get `access_token` and `token_type`, but not `username`.

I don't understand how to implement it.

[image: description in documentation]

when I attempt to do GET request without passing any token or username In response i get message = "Unauthorized"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVGiz.png)

Comment: That's an HTTP GET request to the service URL, describe exactly what you don't understand. You'll pass the request parameters as described.

Comment: I understand that I need pass the request parameter, but I don't know how to get :username parameter, because when user is authorized, in response I get only access_token and token_type, but not username.

Comment: If you are authorized, you know the username right? How did you got authorized? Or you have stored it previously in the session, and you will get username from there, or from some function in the API of the authentication you are using.

Comment: No, I don't have a username, authentication implemented with oauth, and in this case I don't get username, I get only access_token and token_type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this other endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories):

> List repositories that are accessible to the authenticated user.
>
> This includes repositories owned by the authenticated user, repositories where the authenticated user is a collaborator, and repositories that the authenticated user has access to through an organization membership.
>
> ```
> GET /user/repos
> ```

You can set the `visibility` parameter to `private` if you're only interested in private repositories.

You will need to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) your requests, e.g. by including the OAuth token in an `Authorization` header:

```
Authorization: token <your_token_goes_here>
```

or by including an `access_token` parameter with your request:

```
GET https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=<your_token_goes_here>
```

There is no need to pass in the user's username; the authenticated user is automatically used.

Comment: when I attempt to do request without passing any information I only get message = "Unauthorized" in response.

Comment: @ПавелЯкунин, you still need to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication). From your question I thought you already had this part figured out; I have now updated my answer to include information about authenticating.